# reledpar: parallel text keeping a translation in the outside column

Tags: memoir, reledmac, parcolumns, reledpar

I'm using the packages parcolumns and parcolsx to keep my translation on the outside column of the page (so on even pages it would be on the left and for odd pages on the right)

I'm interested in using the packages reledmac/reledpar for other reasons and I'm wondering if there is a built in way to achieve what I have been achieving with parcolumns/parcolsx

example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
           Left hand (even) page      |        Right hand (odd) page
   column 2              column 1     |      column 1              column 2
_translation_  This is the main text  |  This is the main text  _translation_
_translation_  This is the main text  |  This is the main text  _translation_
_translation_  This is the main text  |  This is the main text  _translation_
_translation_  This is the main text  |  This is the main text  _translation_
_translation_  This is the main text  |  This is the main text  _translation_
_translation_  This is the main text  |  This is the main text  _translation_
_translation_  This is the main text  |  This is the main text  _translation_
_translation_  This is the main text  |  This is the main text  _translation_
_translation_  This is the main text  |  This is the main text  _translation_
```

instead of:

```
           Left hand (even) page        |        Right hand (odd) page
     column 1            columm 2       |         column 1          column 2
This is the main text   _translation_   |  This is the main text  _translation_
This is the main text   _translation_   |  This is the main text  _translation_
This is the main text   _translation_   |  This is the main text  _translation_
This is the main text   _translation_   |  This is the main text  _translation_
```

Comment: I am not sur to understand what you need. COuld you reformulate, or better, add a schemas.

Comment: How, i see. for now it is not possible, but please open an issue on github, I will try to do something this week-end (but only if you open an issue)

Comment: Thank you! I just submitted an issue (I hope it's in the right format etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new version of reledpar, v2.15.0, just submitted on CTAN, provides a `movecolumnspositiononrightpage` package option.

Here a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia,fontspec,xunicode}
\usepackage{libertineotf}
\setmainlanguage{english}


\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage[movecolumnspositiononrightpage]{reledpar}
\setlength{\columnrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\setlength{\Lcolwidth}{0.65\textwidth}
\setlength{\Rcolwidth}{0.25\textwidth}


\begin{document}
\begin{english}
\title{Working with outside and inside columns}
\date{}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
This file shows an example of the \verb+movecolumnspositiononrightpage+ option in action. This option allows to have inside and outside columns, rather than left and right columns.
\end{abstract}
\end{english}
\AtBeginPairs{\sloppy}
\begin{pairs}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.
            \pend
                        \pstart
                Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.
            \pend
                        \pstart
                Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.
            \pend
                        \pstart
                Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.
            \pend
                        \pstart
                Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.
            \pend
                        \pstart
                Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.
            \pend
                        \pstart
                Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.
            \pend
                        \pstart
                Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.
            \pend
                        \pstart
                Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.
            \pend
                        \pstart
                Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.
            \pend
                        \pstart
                Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.
            \pend
                        \pstart
                Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph. Inside paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.  Other inside paragraph.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph.
            \pend
                        \pstart
                Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph.
            \pend
                        \pstart
                Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph.
            \pend
                        \pstart
                Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph.
            \pend
                        \pstart
                Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph.
            \pend
                        \pstart
                Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph.
            \pend
                        \pstart
                Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph.
            \pend
                        \pstart
                Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph.
            \pend
                        \pstart
                Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph.
            \pend
                        \pstart
                Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph.
            \pend
                        \pstart
                Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph.
            \pend
                        \pstart
                Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph. Outside paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph. Other outside paragraph.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}

\end{pairs} 
\Columns

\end{document}
```